# CSS not working on textarea

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to CSS - and js/jquery/asp.net etc, currently on a big learning curve! :) - I have the following styling but for some reason it's not working on the textbox - am I missing something really simple here?

```
.label-wrapper
{
    position: relative;
    min-width: 100px;
    max-width: 600px;
    height: 24px;
    display:block;
    margin-left: 10px;

}

.label-wrapper > label
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 85px;
    height: 50px;
}

.label-wrapper > span
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 190px;
    height: 50px;
}

.label-wrapper > button
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 170px;
    width: 300px;
}

.label-wrapper > textarea
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 170px;
}

.label-wrapper > input[Type=Text]
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 170px;
    width: 250px;

}
.label-wrapper > input[id=txtDateReceived]
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 170px;
    width: 100px;

}    

.label-wrapper > input[id=txtDateReceivedTime]
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 280px;
    width: 70px;   
}
.label-wrapper > select
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 170px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 24px;
}
```

See jsfiddle here > http://jsfiddle.net/eoykms9o/

I want the Click Me button to appear under the Notes area, preferably out of the **jobDetails** div

Thanks in advance

Comment: I know you're just learning but this really isn't the way you should be building pages. Using absolute positioning for everything means its stuck to the wall like notes on a message board. You should think of your page more like a flow of one item below another item below another. Check out [Bootstrap](http://www.getbootstrap.com/) for a great starting point for this kind of thing.

Comment: You could also put the form inside a table and everything will look aligned. Using absolute positioning for everything is a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on the absolute positioning - this is a page I'm creating to get some xml/webservice calls functionality working (not included in the code above) and won't actually end up looking like this - it was just annoying me that I couldn't get it aligned. I will look at Bootstrap instead and rebuild it I think. Thanks again

Comment: @rtpHarry: I liked your comment until you mentioned Bootstrap … (which in my eyes is absolutely _not_ a good way to _learn_ how to work with CSS … I rather think it creates “CSS idiots” that get stumped on how to solve even the most trivial formatting problems with CSS if it can’t be done by throwing just another class name onto an element.)

Comment: @CBroe no offense to the OP but I could see they were showing a fundamental gap in CSS knowledge. I agree BS means you miss out on the nitty gritty but not totally sure I want to know all of the details any more. I use Less & a grunt pipeline eg for autoprefixes. BS is great because it sidesteps browser compatibility + gives a baseline. Its a great subject for debate and we could probably bounce it around for days (and I wouldn't be against your views) but at the time I just wanted to give them the simplest route to getting the "I made that" feeling of something working :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution for this is to just add two more `<br />` tags in:

```
        <textarea id="txtNotes" rows="5" cols="50"></textarea>
        </div>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
                    <div class='label-wrapper'>
            <button id="TestButton2" type="button">
                Click me</button>
            <br />
            <br />
        </div>
```

But sorry to say, the page on a whole uses very bad development techniques.

I know you're just learning but this really isn't the way you should be building pages.

Using absolute positioning for everything means its stuck to the wall like notes on a message board. You should think of your page more like a flow of one item below another item below another.

Check out [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) for a great starting point for this kind of thing.

Comment: Yes you could add more <br/> and it woud work, but that's really not the way you want to learn css if you want to improve

Comment: @FrankWinters I totally agree, I did put a comment up at the top but probably should have reiterated it here.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add `Notes:` parent div i.e `<div class"label-wrapper teaxtarea-wrapper">` than put below css on css file:

```
.teaxtarea-wrapper{height: 76px;}
```

Done...

Answer (score 1):

You shoud replace .label-wrapper > button from your css and use this.

```
  .label-wrapper > button {
  left: 190px;
  width: 300px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
textarea{
/*style */
 }
 #txtNotes{
   /*style */
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eoykms9o/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Just add two more `<br/>`

http://jsfiddle.net/eoykms9o/5/

Comment: Yes you could add more <br/> and it woud work, but that's really not the way you want to learn css if you want to improve

Answer (score 0):

> I want the Click Me button to appear under the Notes area, preferably out of the jobDetails div

This happens because of `position: absolute` of `textarea` so parent `div.label-wrapper` cannot set height properly automatically. To fix that you may set height of this `div.label-wrapper` explicitly.

Or do not use `absolute` positioning. I don't see reasons why you are using absolute positioning.

Comment: I think the reason for the absolute positioning was because the dev didn't know how to make the forms items line up next to labels, but I agree this isn't the way things should be done.